# Combinatorics: Group voting amongst themselves

Tags: combinatorics

5 members of a group vote for each other, how many ways can they do so such that they cannot caste a vote for themselves?
I believe it is $4^{5}$ since each member has 4 different possibilities. Am I correct in saying so?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is correct. Person 1 has 4 ways of voting. Person 2 has 4 ways and so on. So you get $4*4*4*4*4$ = $4^{5}$